# SQL Result for all Where Clause Entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2012, I need my query to return a value for each element in the *where* clause.

```
select count(id) idCount, squad from dbo.Project
where id  between 60000 and 80000
and status = ('Complete') and squad in ('Mechanical', 'Civil', 'Electrical', 'Architectural')
and fiscalyear = 2018
group by squad
order by squad asc
```

The query returns

```
idCount Squad
1       Civil
3       Electrical
3       Mechanical
```

What I would like the output to be is

```
idCount     Squad
    0       Architectural
    1       Civil
    3       Electrical
    3       Mechanical
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `left join`.  In SQL Server, you can do:

```
select count(p.id), v.squad
from (values ('Mechanical'), ('Civil'), ('Electrical'), ('Architectural')
     ) v(squad) left join
     dbo.Project p
     on v.squad = p.squad and
        p.id between 60000 and 80000 and
        p.fiscalyear = 2018
group by v.squad
order by v.squad asc ;
```

Note that all the `where` conditions need to go in the `on` clause, to prevent inadvertent filtering of values that do not match.